# Wordembeddings for local languages

Tags: nlp

Word embeddings visualization for local languages like Telugu 
While developing word embeddings for local languages we give input file in bytes under utf-8 encoding scheme. Then how to decode and visualize the proper words in [vectorspace] local languages using tsne?In my tsne plot how to get words in telugu?

[images show encoded bytes to utf-8 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNYF6.png)